# How to recode data within the data frame In R

Tags: r

A sample of data that can be generalised to many columns are as follows

```
id  colour  zm          cinema  pen     wm          monitor mn
1   blue    good        a       wood    bad         24      very good
2   Yellow  bad         b       metal   good enough 23      good
3   Red     good enough d       plastic bad         27      good enough
```

I want to get the following table

```
id  colour  zm  cinema  pen     wm  monitor mn
1   blue    B   a       wood    D   34      A
2   Yellow  D   b       metal   C   23      B
3   Red     C   d       plastic D   27      C
```

very good= A, good= B, good enough=C, bad=D.
I understand it can be done by "mutate", but struggle to do it within a data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use named vector to change the values

```
nm1 <- setNames(LETTERS[1:4], c("very good", "good", "good enough", "bad"))
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
     mutate(across(c(zm, wm, mn), ~ nm1[.]))
```

-output

```
df2
#  id colour zm cinema     pen wm monitor mn
#1  1   blue  B      a    wood  D      24  A
#2  2 Yellow  D      b   metal  C      23  B
#3  3    Red  C      d plastic  D      27  C
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, colour = c("blue", "Yellow", "Red"), 
    zm = c("good", "bad", "good enough"), cinema = c("a", "b", 
    "d"), pen = c("wood", "metal", "plastic"), wm = c("bad", 
    "good enough", "bad"), monitor = c(24L, 23L, 27L), mn = c("very good", 
    "good", "good enough")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get Error: Can't splice an object of type `closure` because it is not a vector

Comment: @user330 Can you show your `packageVersion('dplyr')` I tried with `factor` class as well and it is working for me

Comment: It says ‘1.0.2’, Ok?

Comment: @user330 I also have the same version.  Is the error based on the `data` in my post or is it a different data.  If it is a different, it is better to show the `dput` or `str` to understand the structure

Comment: I think you ok, but when I use your code , I get Error: Can't splice an object of type `closure` because it is not a vector

Comment: @user330 Is it from the same data in my post.  I tried couple of times, and couldn't find any error on that code when applied to the data

Comment: No, my data with different coloumns

Comment: @user330 If you can show the `dput` of a small example that shows the error, it would be easier to debug

Comment: Error is gone, but I get NA

Comment: @user330 Please check if the values in the columns are the same as you showed i.e. if there are leading/lagging spaces etc

Comment: I see the columns are chr in str. Is this because I get NA?

Comment: @user330 No, that is not the issue.  The preferred class is `chr`.  I would assume that your column values are not matching because of some typo in spelling or leading/lagging spaces

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use `forcats::fct_recode`:

```
vars <- c(A = "very good", B = "good", C = "good enough", D = "bad")

library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
data %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character),~fct_recode(.,!!!vars)))
  id colour zm cinema     pen wm monitor mn
1  1   blue  B      a    wood  D      24  A
2  2 Yellow  D      b   metal  C      23  B
3  3    Red  C      d plastic  D      27  C
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use `recode` which makes for good legibility:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(
    zm = recode(zm, "very good" = "A", "good" = "B", "good enough" = "C", "bad" = "D"))

df1
#   id colour zm cinema     pen          wm monitor          mn
# 1  1   blue  B      a    wood         bad      24   very good
# 2  2 Yellow  D      b   metal good enough      23        good
# 3  3    Red  C      d plastic         bad      27 good enough
```

**Edit:** you would, of course, need library [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) as `mutate` and `recode` are part of it.

**Explanation:**
`mutate()` can add or change columns to your dataframe. `recode()` takes, as you expect it, `zm` and substitutes the values and `mutate()` assigns the result back to `zm`.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `match`

```
v <- c("very good", "good", "good enough", "bad")
cols <- c("zm", "wm", "mn")
df[cols] <- LETTERS[seq_along(v)][match(unlist(df[cols]), v)]
```

gives

```
> df
  id colour zm cinema     pen wm monitor mn
1  1   blue  B      a    wood  D      24  A
2  2 Yellow  D      b   metal  C      23  B
3  3    Red  C      d plastic  D      27  C
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = 1:3, colour = c("blue", "Yellow", "Red"),
    zm = c("good", "bad", "good enough"), cinema = c("a", "b",
    "d"), pen = c("wood", "metal", "plastic"), wm = c("bad",
    "good enough", "bad"), monitor = c(24L, 23L, 27L), mn = c("very good",
    "good", "good enough")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```